# Erroneous bindTexture(TEXTURE_2D, null); call, or bad shader? Texture disapparing with three.ShaderMaterial

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl

In two cases, I have a THREE.ShaderMaterial that doesn't doesn't correctly render an object, omitting its texture.
On both examples, the middle object is a basic THREE.MeshPhongMaterial

Example1: http://jsfiddle.net/sG9MP/4/ The object that's closest to the screen never shows.
On this one, it works with renderer.render(...) but not composer.render(...).

```
renderer.render( scene, camera );
//composer.render();
```

Example2: http://jsfiddle.net/sG9MP/5/ Here I'm trying to duplicate the MeshPhongMaterial shader as a base so I can modify it. I tried to replicate it perfectly. I copied the uniform, vert, frag, and replicated what's in the object.  I can't see anything different, so I don't get why it's not working the same as the standard Three.js phong shader.

So it's two cases where I'm using THREE.ShaderMaterial and it's not rendering the shader correctly, and I can't figure out why.  On the second example(which is the one where I really need fixed. The first was an old test), in the webGL inspector I see the scene often looks fine until there is a "bindTexture(TEXTURE_2D, null);" call that happens under the hood by three.js. Though sometimes it just draws without it. In the first example, it's always drawing without it.

I feel like I must be missing some sort of flag in the renderer, or composer, or something. Or in my second example, where I'm trying to copy the Three.js phong shader, maybe I didn't copy something perfectly.

The goal here is just to copy the phong shader, so I can modify the uniform, vert, and frag on it. Sadly, I can't simply .clone() it since the vert and frag can't be modified after it's compiled.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like while ShaderMaterial.map was being set, ShaderMaterial.uniforms.map.value was not consistently set.

I really don't understand this, though. In some cases I had issues not setting things at the top level under ShaderMaterial. Other cases I have issues not setting uniforms.

In my material, I just went and added this:

```
    for(var k in phongMat){
        if( typeof phongMat.uniforms[k] != 'undefined' ){
            phongMat.uniforms[k].value = phongMat[k];
        }
    }
```